# How could i change my user login system to multi tier'ed login

Tags: php

At this time, I have a simple admin login section to my web site, from which an admin could add/edit page content add/edit pages or subjects.
Now, I am thinking down the line in this project for this site to work in the way needed. I need to add multi level users system,
I would think that adding a user level as an `INT` to my table sets would allow this,
then in my pages where I have my `"is_logged_in"` function call I could also call the user level `INT` and store it in the session.
This way if the user is set to level `1` show links `a`,
if the user is set to level `2` show the links `b`.
or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: No, looks great. Go for it.

Comment: Go even deeper and use arrays to store permisions so you can do more granular permision system.

Comment: Your solution is fine if it suits your needs.  At some point you may wish to switch from "levels" to something more flexible, such as "roles" or "permissions" etc.  But there is no point building something you're not using yet (see [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)).

Comment: yes ok I have just done some light reading on your comment @YAGNI and well yes that's left me a little food for thought maybe at some point you would be will to get with me and we can look through what am working for and what I already have

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel. What you're looking for is called Access Control List (ACL) functionality. There are lots of available solutions you can incorporate into your project. Personally I use Zend's Acl libraries but there are many more flavors out there.

How it works (basic version): you assign some ACL roles - e.g. "admin", "staff", "user", "guest" where "guest" would be your default anonymous visitor. When a user logs in, you save the ACL role in the user's session.

You then create an ACL class that assigns these roles to your resources. E.g. "admin" can read and edit anyone's data, "staff" can read "admin", "staff" and "user" data, but only edit its own and "user" data, "user" can read other "user" data but only edit its own data.

At any point in your application where you need to check if a user is allowed to perform some action or access certain sections of a website (e.g. the CMS), you check against your ACL rules to execute the action / allow access or tell the user he/she is not authorized.